# How to find out what init mode system is using?

Tags: 14.04, upstart, systemd, init.d, init

I was looking at this and I'm not sure how to find out which startup service is used on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04 on Digital Ocean). Can it use all of them? (upstart, system v, systemd)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 only uses Upstart. Ubuntu 15.04 onwards use systemd, but on 15.04 you can switch to Upstart. Both Upstart and systemd support sysv init scripts for backward compatibility.

The [Ubuntu Wiki article on Systemd for Upstart users](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#How_to_identify_which_init_system_you_are_currently_booting_with) gives this command for identifying the current init system:

```
ps -p1 | grep systemd && echo systemd || echo upstart
```

This should always return `upstart` on 14.04 or 12.04 (the currently supported versions of Ubuntu not using systemd).

Comment: tnx, that answers my question, I will accept it in 5 minutes, not allowed right now